# jQuery UI dialog - problem with event on close

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to perform a specific action when I close a jQuery UI dialog. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
$('a.open-trigger').click(function(){
    var test = 'hello';

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        dialogClass: 'change', 
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 334, 
        width: 450,
        autoOpen: false,
        show: 'fade'
    });

    $('#dialog').dialog('open');

    $('a.close-trigger').click(function(){
        alert(test);
        $('#dialog').dialog('close');
    });
});
```

The first time I close the dialog, I get the expected alert with the word "hello". If I open the dialog a second time, and close it, I get the "hello" alert twice. If I open and close it a third time, I get three alerts, and so on.

Why are these alerts duplicating themselves? I would want to the alert to only show up once on close, no matter how many times I open/close the dialog.

Thanks!
Simon

Answer (score 8):

You are attaching additional event handlers every time you call `.click`. That is why it is duplicating.

```
$('a.close-trigger').click(function(){
                    alert(test);
                    $('#dialog').dialog('close');
            });
```

Pull that code out onto the same level as the other event binding and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You've bound a function to the open button that adds a event handler to the close button each time the open event is fired.  You should add your close event handler somewhere outside of 'a.open-trigger' event function...

```
$('a.open-trigger').click(function(){
        var test = 'hello';

        $('#dialog').dialog({bgiframe: true, dialogClass: 'change', resizable: false, draggable: false, modal: true, height: 334, width: 450, autoOpen: false, show: 'fade'});
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});

$('a.close-trigger').click(function(){
        alert(test);
        $('#dialog').dialog('close');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the close click event handler out of the open click event handler

```
$(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog({bgiframe: true, dialogClass: 'change', resizable: false, draggable: false, modal: true, height: 334, width: 450, autoOpen: false, show: 'fade'});

    $('a.open-trigger').click(function(){    
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });


    $('a.close-trigger').click(function(){
        alert("hello");
        var myDialog = $('#dialog');
        if (myDialog.dialog('isOpen'))
            myDialog.dialog('close');
    });
});
```