# Jquery: Create a popup window when the mouse pointer enters and leaves the elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create a popup window in the middle of the web browser when the mouse pointer enters and leaves the elements. The pop up window shows an image that I provide.

How should I implement this in Jquery? Or is there any good plugin to do it?

Thanks

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels

Comment: http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/

Comment: lots of tooltip and modal plugins for this, do some searching in google. Questions like these are off topic here

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery UI dialog box.

[DEMO](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

That's quite easy, you can do it like that:

```
$('.hovered_element').mouseenter(function() {
  // you can use some plugin here, or just a simple .show()
  $('.popup_element').show();

  //if you want popup to fade in
  //$('.popup_element').fadein(600);
});
$('.hovered_element').mouseleave(function() {
  // again: any js plugin method, or just .hide()
  $('.popup_element').hide();

  //if you want popup to fade out
  //$('.popup_element').fadeout(600); 
});
```

Of course you need to style your `.popup_element` so it shows up in the center, or anywhere you like.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to coding, I suggest using the jQuery team's jQueryUI library -- which includes a `.dialog()` capability (they call it a "widget"). Here's how it works:

**(1)** Include both jQuery *and* the jQueryUI libraries in your `<head></head>` tags. Note that you must also include an appropriate CSS theme library for jQueryUI (or the dialogs will be invisible):

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**(2)** Create an empty div in your HTML, and initialize it as a dialog:

HTML:

```
<div id="myDlg"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$('#myDlg').dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    modal:true,
    width: 500,
    height: 'auto'
});
```

**(3)** Then, when you are ready to display the dialog, insert new data into the `myDlg` div just before opening the dialog:

```
$('#myDlg').html('<div>This will display in the dialog</div>');
$('#myDlg').dialog('open');
```

Note that you can put any HTML in the `html()` method, including an image.

The above code allows you to change the content of the dialog and use the re-same dialog DIV each time.

---

Here's what the working example would look like:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8jp37ej9/1)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myDlg"></div>
<div id="questiona" class="allques">
    <div class="question">What is 2 + 2?</div>
    <div class="answer">4</div>
</div>
<div id="questionb" class="allques">
    <div class="question">What is the 12th Imam?</div>
    <div class="answer">The totally wacky reason why Iran wants a nuclear bomb.</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var que,ans;

$('#myDlg').dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    modal:true,
    width: 500,
    height: 'auto',
    buttons: {
        "See Answer": function(){
            $('#myDlg').html(ans);
            $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').next('button').hide();
        },
        "Close": function(){
            $('#myDlg').html('').dialog('close');
        }
    }
});

$('.allques').hover(
    function(){
        //hover-IN
        que = $(this).find('.question').html();
        ans = $(this).find('.answer').html();
        $('#myDlg').html(que).dialog('open');
    },
    function(){
        //hover-OUT -- do nothing
    }
```

### );

Resources:

[How to use Plugins for PopUp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797855/how-to-use-plugins-for-popup/18797998#18797998)

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/

[jQuery UI Dialog Box - does not open after being closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366854/jquery-ui-dialog-box-close-function)

[Dynamically changing jQueryUI dialog buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013222/dynamically-changing-jqueryui-dialog-buttons)

[jQuery UI dialog - problem with event on close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865998/jquery-ui-dialog-problem-with-event-on-close)

Comment: Indeed, but not what he's asking for. Are you just coping answers from other questions? :)

Answer (score 0):

Bind the event handler to a mouseout event. See the link for more info:
http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

One way to approach the problem is to create a div(which will hold your popup window) and use the hide and show jquery effects along with it.